# SQL Server 2005 How can I set up an audit table that records the column name updated?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, audit

given this table definition

```
create table herb.app (appId int identity primary key
 , application varchar(15) unique
 , customerName varchar(35),LoanProtectionInsurance bit 
 , State varchar(3),Address varchar(50),LoanAmt money
 ,addedBy varchar(7) not null,AddedDt smalldatetime default getdate())
```

I believe changes will be minimal, usually only a single field, and very sparse.

So I created this table:

```
create table herb.appAudit(appAuditId int primary key
 , field varchar(20), oldValue varchar(50),ChangedBy varchar(7) not null,AddedDt smalldatetime default getdate())
```

How in a trigger can I get the column name of the value of what was changed to store it? I know how to get the value by joining the deleted table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [inserted and deleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) tables.  Nigel Rivett wrote a great [generic audit trail trigger](http://www.nigelrivett.net/AuditTrailTrigger.html) using these tables.  It is fairly complex SQL code, but it highlights some pretty cool ways of pulling together the information and once you understand them you can create a custom solution using his ideas as inspiration, or you could just use his script.

Here are the important ideas about the tables:

- On an insert, inserted holds the inserted values and deleted is empty.
- On an update, inserted holds the new values and deleted holds the old values.
- On a delete, deleted holds the deleted values and inserted is empty.
- The structure of the inserted and deleted tables (if not empty) are identical to the target table.
- You can determine the column names from system tables and iterate on them as illustrated in Nigel's code.

```
    if exists (select * from inserted)
        if exists (select * from deleted)
            -- this is an update
            ...
        else
            -- this is an insert
            ...
    else
        -- this is a delete
        ...

-- For updates to a specific field
SELECT d.[MyField] AS OldValue, i.[MyField] AS NewValue, system_user AS User
FROM inserted i
INNER JOIN deleted d ON i.[MyPrimaryKeyField] = d.[MyPrimaryKeyField]

-- For your table
SELECT d.CustomerName AS OldValue, i.CustomerName AS NewValue, system_user AS User
FROM inserted i
INNER JOIN deleted d ON i.appId = d.appId
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* need this kind of auditing in a way that's critical to your business look at SQL Server 2008's Change Data Capture feature.  That feature alone could justify the cost of an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

something like this for each field you want to track

```
    if UPDATE(Track_ID)
begin

insert into [log].DataChanges
(
    dcColumnName,
    dcID,
    dcDataBefore,
    dcDataAfter,
    dcDateChanged,
    dcUser,
    dcTableName
)
select
'Track_ID',
d.Data_ID,
coalesce(d.Track_ID,-666),
coalesce(i.Track_ID,-666),
getdate(),
@user,
@table
from inserted i
    join deleted d on i.Data_ID=d.Data_ID
        and coalesce(d.Track_ID,-666)<>coalesce(i.Track_ID,-666)

end
```

'Track_ID' is the name of the field, and d.Data_ID is the primary key of the table your tracking.  @user is the user making the changes, and @table would be the table your keeping track of changes in case you're tracking more than one table in the same log table

Answer (score 0):

Here's my quick and dirty audit table solution. (from http://freachable.net/2010/09/29/QuickAndDirtySQLAuditTable.aspx)

```
CREATE TABLE audit(
  [on] datetime not null default getutcdate(),
  [by] varchar(255) not null default system_user+','+AppName(),
  was xml null,
  [is] xml null
)

CREATE TRIGGER mytable_audit ON mytable for insert, update, delete as
INSERT audit(was,[is]) values(
  (select * from deleted as [mytable] for xml auto,type),
  (select * from inserted as [mytable] for xml auto,type)
)
```